# Unable to add service reference in VS 2017 15.5.7

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

I have a VB.NET Core app I'm trying to connect to a remote WCF service. When I try going through the **"Add Connected Service"** routine, no services are listed and a message shows up saying that:

> no connected service is supported for the current project type.

I tried installing the WCF Web Service Reference Provider extension - which IIUC [shouldn't be required anymore since 15.5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/10/11/visual-studio-2017-version-15-5-preview/) - but it made no difference.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: if your web service is restful you cant add it to service references.

Comment: @HosseinBadrnezhad I can't even get as far as putting my service URI in!

Comment: do you published your web service? can you see that in browser?

Comment: @HosseinBadrnezhad Yes I have. There's nothing wrong with the service, I'm positive about that. I can still add a service reference for it to older .NET projects not using the new SDK. It is specifically the tooling for .NET core projects that seems to fail me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like when the .NET Core project is in VB.NET the WCF Web Service Reference Provider isn't available. Quite disappointing if you ask me. :(

Comment: Yup, verified this as well and the only connected service available is "Cloud Storage With Azure Storage".  Also, there is no ASP.Net project option under VB.Net.  You should report this as a VS bug using the feedback button in VS (Upper right hand corner).

Answer (score 3):

First, Uninstall the "WCF Web Service Reference Provider" by going into through Tools -> Extensions and Updates menu in VS.  This has been in VS since the release of VS 15.5.5.  So if you have 15.5.7 then having the extension installed could be causing issues.

---

I created a .Net core application and when I click on the "Connected Services" link I get the following screen.

[image]

Then when I click the "Microsoft WCF Web Services Reference Provider" link I get the following screen.

[image]

I am running VS 15.5.7, so you should see the same screens.  What do you get when you do the same steps?  Can you post some screen shots?

Sorry I could not go past this screen, I did not have a WCF web service I could access to see what the next steps are. If you have issues following the steps above, please post more details about what you are seeing (screenshots would help).  Also, if you have a URL to a public WCF service please post it so I can see if I have the same issue you are having.

Comment: I'm going to grant you the bounty for effort but unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. You did manage to get me one step further though. See my own answer below.

Comment: Glad I was able to help, even though it did not provide a solution.