# Add WSDL to .NET Core Project

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, wsdl, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm going to add WSDL to my .NET Core project. It cannot add a service reference to the project. "No connected service is supported for the current project type" message showing.

Can anyone give me a clue to fix this?

[image]

> Update 1

Version : Visual studio 2017 (V 15.3.5)

Project type : .NET Core Console app

> UPDATE 2

I've tried the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49010154/unable-to-add-service-reference-in-vs-2017-15-5-7) and it is not showing "WCF Web Service Reference Provider" in installed area to uninstall.

[image]

Comment: What is your vs version?What is your project type?Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49010154/unable-to-add-service-reference-in-vs-2017-15-5-7

Comment: Thanks for replying @Xing Zou. I saw the mentioned StackOverflow question before I post my question. But on my computer, there is no any service install with the mentioned name. However, I added, "Update 1" and "Update 2" in my original post.

Comment: It seems that you need to upgrade your vs tool,see my reply.

Answer (score 0):

The WCF Web Service Reference Provider Tool needs Visual Studio 2017 15.5 or later versions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide

Try to upgrade your visual studio to the latest version: Tools->Get Tools and Features